# Procedure to check count, store result and delete records

Tags: postgresql

I want to create stored procedure to check count of query result. Then if count is > 0 to execute some query to delete records in other table. Below see what i got so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myprocedure(tableName VARCHAR, age INT, secondTable VARCHAR)
AS
$$
declare cnt := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %tableName% WHERE ageID =%id%;
declare result;

BEGIN
EXECUTE cnt;

IF cnt >= 1 THEN
        result := SELECT ID FROM %tableName% WHERE ageID =%id%
        --remove records from secondTable
        EXECUTE DELETE FROM %secondTable% WHERE ID IN (result)
END IF;


    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Is a procedure very different from a function? Certainly none of this code would work in a function. If it's plpgsql then please read the documentation on plpgsql as this is all invalid.

Comment: Its procedure i am struggling with convention this is new to me any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) you can't "reference" a variable with `%tableName%` and you certainly can not use a variable within a SQL statement for an identifier. You will need to use dynamic SQL.

You also got the DECLARE part completely wrong. You only write the keyword once, and you have to define a data type for the variables.

To create SQL strings that contain identifier, use `format()` and the `%I` placeholder to properly deal with identifiers that need quoting.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myprocedure(p_tablename VARCHAR, p_age INT, p_secondtable VARCHAR)
AS
$$
declare 
  l_sql text;
  cnt integer; 
BEGIN
   l_sql := format('select count(*) from %I where ageid = :1', p_tablename);
   EXECUTE l_sql
     using p_age
     into cnt;

  IF cnt >= 1 THEN
    l_sql := format('DELETE FROM %I WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM %I where ageid = :1)', p_secondtable, p_tablename);
    EXECUTE l_sql using p_age;
END IF;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

But checking for the count before doing the delete is pretty pointless, you can simply that to a single DELETE statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myprocedure(p_tablename VARCHAR, p_age INT, p_secondtable VARCHAR)
AS
$$
declare 
  l_sql text;
  cnt integer; 
BEGIN
    l_sql := format('DELETE FROM %I WHERE id IN (SELECT t.id FROM %I as t where t.ageid = :1)', p_secondtable, p_tablename);
    EXECUTE l_sql using p_age;
END IF;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Because the DELETE statement won't delete anything if the sub-select doesn't return any rows (which would be the case for `cnt = 0`). And you only need to query the first table once.

Comment: instead of putting %I can i name somehow those? otherwise when having more variables its a bit hard to read.

Comment: @Henry: no, not possible. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for details

Comment: Then you are passing a table name that doesn't exist

Comment: it exists i am passing dbo.MyTable - when i query it normally it gives result . By the way when having no parameter p_age when removing this: using p_age i cannot just use: EXECUTE l_sql  into cnt;  ??

Comment: You probably need to pass `"MyTable"` or something similar. You shouldn't use those dreaded quoted identifiers. And you need to pass schema and table name separately and use `%I.%I` inside the SQL string

Comment: i used a bit diffrent query as such so:  l_sql := format('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I t1 WHERE NOT EXIST(SELECT %I, %I FROM %I.%I t2 WHERE t1.%I = t2.%I AND t1.%I = t2.%I)', pSchema, pChildTable, ChildJoin1, ChildJoin2, pSchema, ParentTable, ChildJoin1, ParentJoin1, ChildJoin2, ParentJoin2);

Comment: but it says "column "childjoin1" does not exist. That strange. I exactly checked one by one all should be fine. Any idea?